# How to fix the Y-axis and normalize density?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, numerical-integration, list-manipulation, subscript

I want to plot a density curve but when I draw the y-axis not getting to 1 (as normalized)

```
  Subscript[a, p]=0.428;Subscript[\[Alpha], p] =1.04;R = 2.45;

Subscript[\[Rho], p1][r_] = Subscript[\[Rho], 0]/((E^((r - R)/Subscript[a, p]) + E^(-((r + R)/Subscript[a, p])))*(0.5*(r/R)^2 + 0.5)^Subscript[\[Alpha], p] + 1)
```

(*I used this code to find Subscript[[Rho], 0] and make the density normalized*)

```
  4*Pi*NIntegrate[Subscript[\[Rho], p1][r]*r^2, {r, 0, Infinity}]

  Plot[Subscript[\[Rho], p1][r], {r, 0, 8}]
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do. You are already integrating over `r`, so doing the integral for different values of `r` does not make much sense. Also, your definition of `Subscript[\[Rho], p]` seems incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to estimate the value of $\rho_0$ using `NIntegrate`:

```
Subscript[a, p] = 0.428; Subscript[α, p] = 1.04; R = 2.45;

Subscript[ρ, 0] = 1/NIntegrate[1/(
   1 + (E^(2.336448598130841` (-2.45` + r)) + 
       E^(-2.336448598130841` (2.45` + r))) (0.5` + 
       0.08329862557267803` r^2)^1.04`), {r, 0, ∞}]
Subscript[ρ, p1][r_] = Subscript[ρ, 0]/((E^((r - R)/Subscript[a, p]) + 
       E^(-((r + R)/Subscript[a, p])))*(0.5*(r/R)^2 + 0.5)^Subscript[α, p] + 1)

Plot[Subscript[ρ, p1][r], {r, 0, 8}]
```

[image: PDF]

And in *Mathematica* you should avoid superscripts and subscripts.  Using `ap` and `αp` would be less prone to unexpected consequences.

Comment: but In Normalization I think we need to multiply by r^2, Like this code

Comment: 4*Pi*NIntegrate[Subscript[\[Rho], p0][r]*r^2, {r, 0, Infinity}]

Comment: Is $\rho_{p_1}(r)$ the density to be normalized or is it $4*\pi*\rho_{p_0}(r)*r^2$ ?

Comment: Sorry , It is rho/p1 must be normalize

Comment: That's the one I normalized.  (So no $r^2$ in there?)

Comment: but I studied that if the Integral from -Infinity to Infinity It is O,k or if the Integre from zero to Infinity I should Multypl by 4*Pi * r^2

Comment: Then please give the full information in your question and remove the parts that are irrelevant.  Does your random variable go from $0$ to $\infty$ or from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ ?